# What will Oracle do when deadlock occurs between two user sessions

Tags: oracle

When a dead lock occurs between two user sessions, what will Oracle do?

Comment: What does the manual say?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle will rollback the transaction which detected the deadlock and raise ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource. Deadlock can occur between two sessions but can also occur in a single session when autonomous transactions are used. You can identify which sessions got rolled back and which SQL caused the deadlock by examining the tracefile that gets generated.
Please see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/consist.htm) and [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/deadlocks).

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 'clears' the deadlock by killing the session that caused the deadlock. This is fully automatic. You only get message in the logfile and the user gets an error message.